# Why was Clifford D. Simak chosen as a winner of the Bram Stoker Award for Lifetime Achievement?

Tags: horror, clifford-d-simak

Clifford D. Simak in 1987 received the Bram Stoker Award for Lifetime Achievement. While I have read and enjoyed a lot of Simak's works (the amazing novel *City*, short stories like "The Big Front Yard", or "Grotto of the Dancing Deer"), he never struck me as a horror writer.

Asking a similar question on reddit turned up *All Flesh is Grass* as an answer. What I could find about this novel sounds more like science fiction than horror, and even if counted as horror, one novel seems hardly enough for a 'Lifetime of Achievement'.

Is there a specific reason he won, or are there other (significant) works I'm not aware of?

Comment: Based on reading his [bibliography](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clifford_D._Simak_bibliography) I can't explain it.  I've read several of his works but nothing that IMHO would be considered horror

Comment: The [requirements](https://www.thebramstokerawards.com/lifetime-achievement-award/lifetime-achievement-award-2/) for the award don't give much guidance as to why either

Comment: FWIW, the way I read *City* it could be seen as horror...

Comment: Change the word "recommend" to "identify" and it's a perfectly valid question.

Comment: @fez, I rewrote that part of my question.

Comment: Not sure how many stories Simak wrote, but it should be a finite list - I’ve retracted my close vote

Comment: FWIW, none of his works are tagged as "horror" in ISFDb, his entry in the SF Encyclopedia doesn't mention horror, and he doesn't even have an entry in the *Encyclopedia of Fantasy and Horror Fiction*.  (These are concrete facts I can point to beyond the fact that I don't recall any of his works I would personally categorize as "horror.")

Comment: http://www.eldritchdark.com/forum/read.php?1,11607 asks the same question, and people mainly mention *City*.

Comment: "The Call from Beyond" has more than a hint of Lovecraft about it (albeit with SF elements too), as does "Where Evil Dwells".

Comment: Rather than asking for a list of his works that may or may not qualify as horror (subjective), I've edited to focus the question on why he actually won the award (objective)

Comment: I've sent a message to https://www.thebramstokerawards.com/ to see if they can elucidate us.

Comment: @FuzzyBoots - "*Because we wanted the publicity"*

Comment: @Valorum - You are reducing my more general question to the win of the Bram Stoker Lifetime Achievement Award. I do not agree with this, but I do not feel like starting an edit war either.

Comment: @Gonger - You are welcome to revert it to the original, at which point it will be immediately closed for being an opinion-based list question.

Comment: https://www.michaelmay.online/2016/08/the-call-from-beyond-hp-lovecraft-and.html

Comment: Or a very short "none of his stories are listed as horror on these prominent sites".

Comment: He was 83 years old and wasn't going to be around much longer. He died in April 1988. I don't know when in 1988 the 1987 awards were given out, but these days they give them out at StokerCon in May.

Answer (score 5):

It seems that The Bram Stoker Horror Writer Association no longer has records on why he was awarded.

> Hello Sean,
>
> Thank you for the inquiry, but unfortunately that was long before I joined the organization and HWA doesn't have records going that far back. Sorry we can't help!
>
> Lisa Morton
>
> for HWA

Comment: Interesting. I've seen a few people who were at the ceremony. It might be worth asking them...

Comment: I tried to find a contemporaneous fanzine report on the award, but so far all I found is a bare announcement with no details https://www.fanac.org/fanzines/Matrix/Matrix78.pdf